# Legitimacy of transforming data before statistical tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, data-transformation, outliers

I have two groups of samples (N=4 for each) and found that there is one outlier for each group (both are higher than the rest of the respected samples within the groups).

I have no resources to repeat the experiment again, and not sure if there is a valid reason for excluding these outliers. Given the sad story of all biologists who have to get a p-value < 0.05, I am thinking of transforming the data.

I somehow found log-transform coupled with square-root transform produce a decent result. These are imaging samples, which I am trying to first normalize the total intensity to the "square root" of the area, then take a "natural log". May I know whether this is legit?

non-parametric is not a real option for me because of the low power for a total number of samples of 8.

Or indeed, I can really claim there is a batch effect of samples and exclude them, because these two are measured from the same batch. Though I think excluding outlier is the last option.

Comment: I fear that, by testing many different transformations until you found one that works, you already ruined your statistical analysis by [tag:p-hacking].

Comment: @Dave, thanks for your comment. Yes, I am also afraid of p-hacking stuff. But, indeed, all transformations and even removing the outliers do not change the trends. I truly believe there are batch effects (though not sure how to formally test this from the small sample size). Both of the samples are skewed in the same direction. I think the normality of the data is not satisfied. Thus, transformation is necessary (?). The problem is what would be a valid transformation.

Comment: I also find myself troubled by what you describe as an outlier. The highest value is not an outlier just because it is larger than all of the others.

Comment: It is essentially impossible to identify an "outlier" in any group of four unless you are basing that assessment on additional information or assumptions about the possible distributions of the four values.  Neither do you have the freedom to transform the data, because that will use up one or two of your (extremely few) degrees of freedom, making it impossible to obtain a significant p-value for any comparison between the two groups unless they are completely separated by some threshold. You just aren't in a position to be formally testing anything.

Comment: It's not always true to say that transformations use up degrees of freedom (or information) because in many cases the transformation is applied because of known properties of the data and the relationship between the data and the intended statistical model. Drug EC50s, for example, are well known to have (almost always) a log-normal distribution and so a log transform of EC50 is appropriate. (Determination of the log EC50 rather than EC50 is equivalent.)

Comment: @MichaelLew That's true, but the transformations being applied here seem to be attempts to trick a hypothesis test into giving $p<0.05$ rather than being based on any kind of theory.

Comment: Uncertainty about how to transform Y is the greatest source of model uncertainty, i.e., what leads to the greatest distortion of statistical inference.  And don't talk about outliers in this context (see nice comments from others).  The only hope for valid frequentist inference in your case is to use a nonparametric test (because it is transformation-invariant and not hurt by outliers).  You should almost forget about p-values with small sample sizes though, and concentrate on uncertainty intervals.

Comment: The assertion that nonparametric tests have lower power than parametric tests is (a) untrue in general, since it depends on the circumstances and (b)  doesn't apply in a situation where you know the assumptions of a parametric test you have in mind to be false (that's why you're talking about outliers and transformations). It seems *especially* weird when  you're  seriously contemplating dropping 25% of the data for some subgroups and not worrying about the impact of that on significance level and power. Similarly for data-driven choice of transformation.

Comment: @Dave Yes, that's true, but it is at the same time not a reason to give anyone the impression that data transformations are inappropriate per se.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Probably true of ranks-based tests, but not every nonparametric test is transformation-invariant. The power of permutations tests done using means can be affected by data transformations.

Comment: Two-group comparisons using all the commonly used nonparametric tests are transformation-invariant.